# CsvBindByPosition : value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression

Tags: java, spring-annotations, opencsv, compile-time, compile-time-constant

I am trying to read a CSV file whose header position numbers comes from a property file.
I get the position number for the fields using @Value. But however I am unable to bind this value as the position for `@CsvBindByPosition`.

Here is my code :

```
public class MyPojo {

    @Value(value = "${csv.pojo.refNumber}")
    public static final int test;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = test)
    private String id;
}
```

This gives me this error:

> The value for annotation attribute `CsvBindByPosition.position` must be a constant expression

Is there a way to resolve this as my position needs to be read from a property file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [MWiesner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2849346/mwiesner) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74591194/7928721), annotation value can't be set in runtime.

What we need is some way to configure the column position mapping in **runtime** instead.

- [`MappingStrategy`](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/MappingStrategy.html) is the interface configure mapping between csv and bean.
- And [`ColumnPositionMappingStrategy`](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/ColumnPositionMappingStrategy.html) is the implementation ready for use in this case.

```java
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;
import com.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategyBuilder;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.io.StringReader;

@SpringBootTest(
        classes = CsvByPositionInRuntimeTest.Pojo.class,
        properties = {"csv.pojo.refNumber=0", "csv.pojo.name=1"}
)
public class CsvByPositionInRuntimeTest {
    // assume 0
    @Value("${csv.pojo.refNumber}")
    private Integer refNumberIndex;
    // assume 1
    @Value("${csv.pojo.name}")
    private Integer nameIndex;

    // or specify column order like 'refNumber,name'
    // this is more readable and easy to maintain
    @Value("${csv.pojo.columnOrder}")
    private String[] columnOrder;

    @Test
    public void parse() {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(
                new StringReader("""
                        123,david
                        456,terry
                        """)
        ).build();
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Pojo> positionMappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategyBuilder<Pojo>().build();
        // this is just for demo, proper implementation is need for all column index
        positionMappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(refNumberIndex < nameIndex ? new String[]{"refNumber", "name"} : new String[]{"name", "refNumber"});
        // positionMappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columnOrder);
        positionMappingStrategy.setType(Pojo.class);
        CsvToBean<Pojo> csvModelCsvToBean =
                new CsvToBeanBuilder<Pojo>(csvReader).withMappingStrategy(
                        positionMappingStrategy
                ).build();
        csvModelCsvToBean.parse().forEach(m -> System.out.println("id:%s ,name:%s".formatted(m.refNumber, m.name)));
    }

    public static class Pojo {
        private String refNumber;
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting workaround. I've added two lines to your test so that it runs out of the box.

Comment: Thank you @samabcde . Yes this is something that will help me get to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The value for the annotation's parameter `position` must be a *[compile time constant](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compile-time-constants#1-compile-time-constants)*, so there is **no** way to achieve what you're aiming for.

Why? In the given code snippet, the *value* of the (pseudo-) constant is not (explicitly) declared at compile time. Hence, even if some value is injected at *runtime*, that will be too late. For further details, I'd recommend reading this [blog entry](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-attribute-value-restrictions).

In other words: The compiler can't ensure that `test` has a known numerical value during compilation which it can use for replacement for compiling code that refers to it. Even worse, it issues another compilation error:

> Variable `test` might not have been initialized.

That violates the idea of a *constant* as there is *no* known (initialization) value. More directly: you can't circumvent a programming languages' [hard requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

In sum: Reconsider, whether a hard-coded *position* value for `test` is suited for your application. At least with OpenCSV it seems to be necessary to define your data format for processing upfront, that is: statically.